# How can I get TFS merge to not try to recover a deleted file

Tags: tfs

In our repository in version 12 we have the file dave.cs. In version 13 we have deleted it. Every time we merge from 12 -> main -> 13, it asks if we want to copy dave.cs on the main-> 13 merge.

How can we tell TFS that we do not want dave.cs copied back up to 13?

Comment: is it showing as a conflict? If so then you can choose "Keep Target" and check in the change. Once you've resolved the conflict TFS should remember. If not then do as others have suggested and merge the file on it's own from Main to 13 but discard the merge. I.e. `tf merge $/TP/Main/dave.cs $/TP/13/dave.cs /discard"

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you have changed 12/dave.cs after deleting it in 13.
In this case, you may merge the corresponding changeset **for that file** with the /discard switch using tf.exe

Whenever you will change 12/dave.cs again you may have the same effect and have to redo the discard. It is proposed again because the new change might actually be relevant now.

Comment: Correct, I have edited 12/dave.cs and am then merging a bunch of changed files up to 13 (via main). Is there some way to tell TFS that it should remain deleted in 13 unless I explicitly undelete it?

Comment: no, not to my knowledge. as stated above, I suppose this is because TFS might never know what you changed and if the change might be relevant to the branch.